# Why does my code execute correctly when I run it from developer pane but doesn't when run with a button?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand why when I run my code from the developer pane, my code run smoothly but when I use a button to run it, it doesn't run correctly.
here's my code and the examples of when it works and when it doesn't

```
Sub Comment()
Dim x As Integer

x = 3

Do Until Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19) = ""
If Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19) <> "N/A" Then

If Sheets(2).Cells(x, 7).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 3).Value And Sheets(2).Cells(x, 16).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 16).Value And Sheets(2).Cells(x, 2).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 2).Value Then
                     'copy the value of the missing label and delete the missing label row
                    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 3).Copy (Cells(x, 3))
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 4).Copy (Cells(x, 4))
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 5).Copy (Cells(x, 5))
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 6).Copy (Cells(x, 6))
                    Sheets(2).Rows(x + 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
                    'calculate the delta for the frequecy and the %
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x, 11).Value = Abs(Cells(x, 5).Value - Cells(x, 9).Value)
                    Sheets(2).Cells(x, 12).Value = Abs(Cells(x, 6).Value - Cells(x, 10).Value)
                    'replace the comment to identify witch one have been change by the tool
                    If Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19) = "Orphan Label" Then Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19).Value = "Was Orphan Label"
                    If Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19) = "Orphan Label - Rate instability" Then Sheets(2).Cells(x, 19).Value = "Was Orphan Label - Rate instability"
                    Sheets(2).Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Sheets(2).Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    GoTo next_row
                End If
End If

next_row:


x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

That's the correct one (when run with developer pane)

[image]

That's the wrong one (when run with a button)

[image]

Comment: you need to apply sheet parentage to all range objects.

Comment: Because you did not tell VBA in which workbook/worksheet your `Cells` objects are. There are some `Cells(x + 1, 3).Copy (Cells(x, 3))` without a worksheet specified. Make sure there is no one without and it will work. Same for any `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` objects. • If the issue persists please [edit] and update the code in your question and leave a comment.

Comment: Also note that `Sheets(2)` is the second sheet in the tab bar at the bottom. If someone moves sheets around your code will break. So re-think if you really mean the second sheet or if you actually mean a sheet named `Sheet2` in VBA which then would be `Sheet2.Cells`. Or a sheet which tab name is `Sheet2` which would be `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells`. Note that these are 3 independent sheet naming systems and `Sheet(2)`, `Sheet2` and `Worksheet("Sheet2")` can be three completely different sheets. Make sure you know how these naming systems work to decide which one you need.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ well since my workbook is start with one sheet and my code ask to the user to open a sheet from another workbook (witch become the sheets(2)) it's the right way i want to use! plus after using the tool, the sheet is delete so every time the user import a sheet it's always the sheet(2) but after adding the sheets parenting it still doesn't work! have you some other tip?

Comment: @alexilas Well, then `Sheets(2)` looks to be good, just wanted to be sure. Can you please [edit] your question and add the full relevant code part as well as how you edited it according to our suggestions? We need to see it in order to help you. Also see [mcve].

Comment: Note that `Sheets(2).Cells(x + 1, 3).Copy (Cells(x, 3))` there is another `Cells` without sheets. I can spot at least 8 of them in your code. Please check again carefully that **all** of them have a sheet specified. If the issue persists don't forget to update your question. • Also note that your `GoTo next_row` does not do anything. You can safely remove that (at least in the code you showed it does nothing useful).